# Intellisense show wrong properties for a Promise inside `async` method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, javascript-intellisense

I've noticed that, when a Promise is used inside an `async` method, a lot of properties which should be in the IntelliSense are actually there.
Take this simple code for example (i'm using REACT and I'm inside a Hook component, just for give you a context).

```
const notAsyncMethod = () => {
    let a : Promise<string> = new Promise(null);
}

const asyncMethod = async () => {
    let a : Promise<string> = new Promise(null);
}
```

Now, in the first case, this is the IntelliSense suggestions:
[image]

Which is exactly what I expect.

Then, in the second case, this is what IntelliSense suggests me:
[image]

Why is this happening? Is it normal, or there might be some problem with my code? And, if this is how it should work.. Why is this happening, and from what those properties are coming?

Comment: Seems like Intellisense is assuming that promises are `await`ed when inside an async function. Its suggestions seem to indicate that it thinks your `Promise<string>` is just a string.

Comment: Any idea why? Else, that assumption is wrong, am I right? Because if so, I could report this issue.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.